# Handling <ng-content> events on parent in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Inside  I have two input boxes. Pushing the #confirmButton works fine, it just submits the form and takes the values from the two inputs. However, if I type in the inputs and then press enter, I get this exception:

```
core.umd.js:3370 EXCEPTION: Error in ./MdInput class MdInput - inline template:0:1054 caused by: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:3370next @ core.umd.js:6838schedulerFn @ core.umd.js:6088SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:223SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:172Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:125Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:89Subject.next @ Subject.js:55EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js:6080onError @ core.umd.js:6303onHandleError @ core.umd.js:6179ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:113NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded @ core.umd.js:6187NgZone.runGuarded @ core.umd.js:6419outsideHandler @ platform-browser.umd.js:1829ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:236Zone.runTask @ zone.js:136ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:304
core.umd.js:3372 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.
```

I'm pretty sure the exception goes away if I'd call enableProdMode(), but that is not a fix.

Template example:

```
<form class="row" (ngSubmit)="_confirm()">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <div class="row col-md-100 button-container">
        <button md-button type="button" (click)="_cancel()">{{'translate.button.cancel' | translate}}</button>
        <span class="col-fill"></span>
        <button md-button color="primary" #confirmButton>{{'translate.button.confirm' | translate}}</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Any reasonable fixes for this would be great, I'd much prefer fixing this parent then go into all the children that use it.
Thanks!

EDIT:
So far I have tried triggering the onSubmit event, and overriding the keydown event, all on the parent - haven't figured this out yet and I'm running out of options.